# Trying to write a Node.js mult-tier application like I'm use to in c#

Tags: node.js, express

I've written multi-tier apps in c# like one listed below.

It made it easy to do full-stack testing.

I've been researching Node.js for weeks now and can't seem to find this kind of separation, especially a business logic layer.

> Am I missing something obvious?
>
> Would TypeScript be a better choice?

Layers:
DTO - Data Transfer Objects
DAL - Data Access Layer
BUS - Business Logic Layer
UI - User Interface

Here's a partial task application of all the layers:

```
using App.BusinessLogicLayer;
using App.DataAccessLayer;
using App.DataTransferObjects;
using System;

namespace App.DataTransferObjects
{
    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace App.DataAccessLayer
{
    public class Tasks
    {
        public static Task Get()
        {
            return new Task() { Id = 1, Name = "Task 1" };
        }
    }
}

namespace App.BusinessLogicLayer
{
    public interface ITaskContext
    {
        Task Get();
    }

    public class TaskContext : ITaskContext
    {
        public Task Get()
        {
            return Tasks.Get();
        }
    }

    public class TaskManager
    {
        ITaskContext _taskContext;
        public TaskManager() : this (new TaskContext())
        {

        }

        public TaskManager(ITaskContext taskContext)
        {
            _taskContext = taskContext;
        }

        public Task Get()
        {
            return _taskContext.Get();
        }
    }
}

namespace App.UserInterface
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TaskManager tm = new TaskManager();
            Console.WriteLine(tm.Get().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is preventing you from creating these constructs in JavaScript?

Comment: Also, yes, TypeScript or ES6 will help you write code more similar to what you have in C#. TS has explicit interfaces, and ES6 brought modules with imports/exports to JS (this is also available in TS).

Comment: Node.js/Express weren't born in the enterprise environment. As a result you won't see concepts such as DTO, VO, DAO, etc. You will commonly see MVC, but nothing more. Node.js and the Express micro framework is more for microservices. Don't overcomplicate it by introducing enterprise weight to it.